# How to find the location of the variable on which bind data column?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm

How to find the location of the variable on which bind data column? A simple search on SOLUTION fails.

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="15"
Binding="{Binding Accounts[0].AccountValue,
Converter={StaticResource DecimalConverter}}"
                          CanUserSort="False"
                          CellStyle="{StaticResource RightAlignCellStyle}"
                          Header="Account Value"
                          HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DefaultDataGridColumnHeaderStyleRight}"
                                            IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Comment: Can you post your entire data grid?

Comment: Can you clarify the question "How to find the location of the variable on which bind data column?" that is not clear to me what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out where the DataContext is set. It can be on the object itself, or any of its parents. The variable `Accounts` should be a property of the DataContext object.